# Is it possible to create a chain of dependencies in fastapi?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I want to get json and validate it. I can't just use pedantic @validator because additional validation requires a database connection or other I/O. How should I use all these checks correctly?

This is something that I want (just enumerate all dependencies for Body param)

```
from __future__ import annotations
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body, Depends
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class ImportModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    text: str | None

def f1(req: ImportModel = Body()):
    if extra_check1(req):
        return req
    raise RequestValidationError("f1")

def f2(req: ImportModel = Body()):
    if extra_check2(req):
        return req
    raise RequestValidationError("f2")

def f3(req: ImportModel = Body()):
    if extra_check3(req):
        return req
    raise RequestValidationError("f3")

#etc...

@app.post('/import')
def import_smth(req: ImportModel = Depends(f1, f2, f3)):
    return req
```

Comment: Is there any good reason for separating each into a separate dependency? Usually you'd be better off by writing `req: ImportModel = Depends(valid_import_model_from_body)`, then letting `valid_import_model_from_body` call the three separate functions that signifies a valid import model (and generally, let a ImportModelService perform the validation so that the business logic is kept outside of the controller). This also lets you validate the import model outside of it being present as a Body in a request.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is perform checks without returning anything (new), you can just use the [`dependencies`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-in-path-operation-decorators/) parameter of your path operation decorator:

```py
@app.post("/import", dependencies=[Depends(f1), Depends(f2), Depends(f3)])
def import_smth(req: ImportModel):
    return req
```